# ipv6 and iptables - setting up basic rules

Tags: ipv6, ip6tables

I have come to realise my IPv6 ports are not going through iptables, and thus are accessible for attacks. I haven't seen any yet, but I'm sure its only a matter of time. As such, I'm trying to shore up the firewall for ipv6. I came across this script that configures the `ip6tables` rules:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ip6tables single-host firewall script

# Define your command variables
ipt6="/sbin/ip6tables"

# Flush all rules and delete all chains
# for a clean startup
$ipt6 -F
$ipt6 -X

# Zero out all counters
$ipt6 -Z

# Default policies: deny all incoming
# Unrestricted outgoing

$ipt6 -P INPUT DROP
$ipt6 -P FORWARD DROP
$ipt6 -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Must allow loopback interface
$ipt6 -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Reject connection attempts not initiated from the host
$ipt6 -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP

# Allow return connections initiated from the host
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Accept all ICMP v6 packets
$ipt6 -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT

# Optional rules to allow other LAN hosts access to services. Delete $ipt6 -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP

# Allow DHCPv6 from LAN only
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp -s fe80::/10 --dport 546 -j ACCEPT

# Allow connections from SSH clients
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic 
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow access to SMTP, POP3, and IMAP
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m multiport --dport 25,110,143 -j ACCEPT
```

While this does stop what I wanted, it also seems to not allow 80 and 443 ports?

```
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ipt6 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

It simply hangs when I try and access from another server:

```
curl -v -6 http://backups.foo.org:80
* Rebuilt URL to: http://backups.foo.org:80/
*   Trying 2a00:1098:80:a1::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

ipv4 works fine:

```
curl -v -4 http://backups.foo.org:80
* Rebuilt URL to: http://backups.foo.org:80/
*   Trying 93.93.135.111...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to backups.foo.org (93.93.135.169) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: backups.foo.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 07:52:32 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 162
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://backups.foo.org/
<
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host backups.foo.org left intact
```

What am I missing? Basically, I just want to block ipv6 ports on services that are sensitive (MySQL, Exim, SMTP etc).

**UPDATE:** As suggested, I have removed:

`$ipt6 -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP`

Then run the script again, and the `ip6tables` looks like this now:

```
root@backups:~# ip6tables --list -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0
ACCEPT     all      ::/0                 ::/0                 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmpv6    ::/0                 ::/0
ACCEPT     udp      fe80::/10            ::/0                 state NEW udp dpt:546
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp      ::/0                 ::/0                 state NEW multiport dports 25,110,143

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have tested it:

```
curl -6 backups.foo.org
curl: (7) Failed to connect to backups.foo.org port 80: Connection refused
```

Again, it works with `-4`. The weird thing is that it does work from here:

https://tools.keycdn.com/ipv6-ping

I can ping from the same server, and it works fine:

```
ping backups.foo.org
PING backups.chambresdhotes.org(2a00:1098:80:a1::1 (2a00:1098:80:a1::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1098:80:a1::1 (2a00:1098:80:a1::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1098:80:a1::1 (2a00:1098:80:a1::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=1.03 ms
^X^C
```

As requested, the output of `ip6tables-save` as well:

```
 ip6tables-save
# Generated by ip6tables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Feb 23 08:57:59 2021
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [78:6090]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s fe80::/10 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 546 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m multiport --dports 25,110,143 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As requested, the output from  `ss -lnpt`. Interestingly, I don't see port 80 in there.

```
LISTEN    0    100  [::]:993       [::]:*  
LISTEN    0    100  [::]:995       [::]:*  
LISTEN    0    128  [::]:22122       [::]:*  
LISTEN    0    100  [::]:110       [::]:*  
LISTEN    0    128 ::1]:783       [::]:*   
LISTEN    0    100  [::]:143       [::]:*  
LISTEN    0    128  [::]:55413       [::]:*  
LISTEN    0    128 *:8181         *:*      
LISTEN    0    128 ::1]:53       [::]:*
LISTEN    0    128  [::]:55414   [::]:*
LISTEN    0    128  [::]:22      [::]:*
LISTEN    0    128 [::1]:8953    [::]:*
```

Interestingly though, it shows up with `netstat`:

```
sudo netstat -tulpan | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9183            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1133/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 93.93.135.169:80        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1161/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8084          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1161/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 93.93.135.169:443       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1161/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1161/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1161/nginx: master
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51104         127.0.0.53:53           ESTABLISHED 1135/nginx: worker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the lesson not to use security scripts without understanding any single line.

I suspect this part is a culprit:

```
# Reject connection attempts not initiated from the host
$ipt6 -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j DROP
```

It really disables any incoming TCPv6 communication. It also must disable any "related" TCPv6 communication (for instance, "active" FTP), because it appears before ctstate line.

Just remove it. It is useless. All unmatched packets will be dropped by the policy anyway, so why dropping anything early in the chain, without leaving a possibility to selectively enable services? I don't understand why ever this line appeared in the script.

Comment: thanks. I've removed that and re-run the script. While `ip6tables --list -n` looks better now, I still don't seem to be able to access it with curl from another server (I've updated the question above with a bit more info)

Comment: please use `ip6tables-save` to display a ruleset. `ip6tables --list` sometimes hides additional info and presents a ruleset in the way it is harder to follow (at least, for me). Also, check with `tcmpdump` if TCP packets ever reach this server.

Comment: thanks - I've updated the post with the results of `ip6tables-save`. I just tested tcpdump on the destination server, and nothing shows up at all. I've tried calling it from 2 different servers

Comment: ah ok so it seems like its NOT the rules doing it. I just rebooted the server, and that cleared out the ip6tables setup of rules. Then tested with: `curl -v -6 backups.foo.org`. It gets the right IP, but fails with: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to backups.foo.org port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: What is `ipv6-icmp`? I didn't noticed that. I used to enable just `icmpv6`. Try to replace. The problem with that may be icmpv6 is needed for NDP to work, and it isn't working now. You can check that with ip -6 neigh show on all machines. Also check `ss -lnpt` to see if anything is listening on ipv6 sockets.

Comment: interestingly changing `$ipt6 -A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT` to `$ipt6 -A INPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT` , still shows as `-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT` on ip6tables-save! (I doublt checked its not a cache by commenting out, and its 100% what that rule is adding). Very odd!

Comment: I have updated my question with the output from `ss -lnpt`. It seems port 80 isn't in there for some reason

Comment: OMG you have to be kidding me. Seems like nginx wanted a reboot on the server I'm trying to connect to! I think we are good now :) Thanks for persevering with me! I'm confident it was your answer that sorted it, so have marked it as so